# Windows Mobile unsign app security prompt

Tags: security, windows-mobile, unsigned

I have a windows mobile app (mymobiler) that i am trying to install and run in my windows mobile phone. As soon as it gets installed it prompts the user with Yes/No option whether to let the program run in the device.

Is there anyway to by pass this? I understand this is just one time , but i just want to know whether if i can avoid that prompt?

Note: There might be a solution like edit some registry key in windows mobile, but again for installing reg editor i need to access the windows mobile keypad for the same reason (YES/NO prompt for regedit app)..

So is there any way to do this process without having to touch the winmob keypad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Mobile Device Security Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb278107.aspx) to change the [device provisioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894922.aspx). Adding a cert may also help.  [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512651.aspx) covers the different security models and what each means to the developer and end-user.